# Multiple filter conditions in Angular2

Tags: angular

Note: I'm new to software development, been functional consultant (non-technical) all these years.

I have a list of array being displayed using *ngFor as below:

```html
<li *ngFor="let borrower of borrowers">
    <p>{{borrower.name}},{{borrower.amount}},{{borrower.rate}},{{borrower.tenure}},{{borrower.city}}<p>
</li>
```

Name is the string. Amount is the number that can take any value between 25000 to 100000. Rate is the number that can range from 12% to 20%. Tenure is the number that can take a value either 6 or 12. City is the string.

I want to filter the above array based on certain filter conditions as below:

```html
<form>
    <input type="text" name="city" placeholder="Enter City" style="width: 100%">
    <div class="amtcheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="25kto50k">25000 - 50000</div>
    <div class="amtcheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="50kto100k">50001 - 100000</div>
    <div class="ratecheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="12to15">12% - 15%</div>
    <div class="ratecheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="16to20">16% - 20%</div>
    <div class="tenurecheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="6months">6 Months</div>
    <div class="tenurecheckbox"><input type="checkbox" name="12months">12 Months</div>
</form>
```

The filter if applied will have at least one or more of the conditions.

This is my first question here. Please let me know if I'm missing something, will improve on next questions.

Answer (score 2):

You can achieve this using a [pipe](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/guide/pipes.html) on your *ngFor. The pipe would need to take each one of your checkbox values in as a series of args. Then you would use those args to reduce the result set down based on your criteria. Here is a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/FZW7SVnWmrQWtVDmBvCZ) if you need more details. The syntax to add a pipe to a *ngFor looks like this

```
*ngFor="let people of peopleCollection | customFilterPipe:hasFeetChckbx:hasScooterChckbx:hasBikeChckbx:hasCarChckbx"
```

Each ":" seperates each arg going into the pipe. The pipe transform method signature will look like this

```
transform(_initialCollection: People[], _hasFeet: boolean, _hasScooter:boolean, _hasBike:boolean, _hasCar:boolean)
```

_initialCollection is the data from the *ngFor collection, all parameters after that are being passed from the *ngFor in each ":".

Comment: Dan, please provide a plunkr with more information. Your help is much appreciated. FYI, listing and filters are different components.

Comment: Updated the answer with a punkr. When it comes to having the filters and listings in two different components, I would start with just one component to make sure the pipe is working correctly. Once that is complete and working the way you want you can split them out into different components. Then use Output and Input from each component to pass data back and forth. If you have more questions specifically about two components communicating, you will want to ask a new SO question.

Comment: Dan, this is very much helpful. Can you please build the plunkr based on my data & conditions? Like I said, I'm very new to this and I'm having trouble understanding on list can be filtered based on a range as well as multiple conditions. Thanks again.